# How to Show Select Value in Edit Form in Node.js CRUD Application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a CRUD application using node.js, express and MongoDB. I want to show the select field value in the edit form. Currently, I am using this code

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <select id="courseName" class="form-control" name="student[course]" value="<%= student.course %>" required>
     <option value="MDCA">MDCA</option>
     <option value="ADCA">ADCA</option>
     <option value="DCA">DCA</option>
     <option value="HARDWARE AND APPLIANCES">HARDWARE AND APPLIANCES</option>
</select>
</div>
```

My app.js edit route is below

```
app.get("/student/:id/edit", function (req, res) {
    Student.findById(req.params.id, function (err, foundStudent) {
        if (err) {
            res.redirect("/students");
        } else {
            res.render("edit", {
                student: foundStudent
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am new to this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the issue basically? ,what does foundStudent contains?

Comment: Just print the foundStudent object in the else block and check all required data is present in that object.

Comment: I want to show the select input field prefilled with the value which is previously filled in the Create route.

Comment: @MeyyappanSubramaniyan I checked the values in MongoDB. All the data are shown there. And here is the object which is printed ```{
_id: "5dd22ae8a90b252b9849abc3",
course: "DCA",
name: "Anand Kuamr",
gurdianName: "Kumar Atanu",
gender: "Male",
caste: "Scheduled Caste",
dob: "2000-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
phone: "111211212",
address: "12115 jdjod",
aadhaar: "0000 2225 5599",
created: "2019-11-18T05:23:52.144Z",
__v: 0
} ```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Could you tell me what is course attribute present in the student. Is 'student.course' just a string or an object?

Comment: The course is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<select>
<%
var options = ["MDCA", "ADCA", "DCA", "HARDWARE AND APPLIANCES" ];
for ( var i = 0; i < options.length; i++ )
{
    var isSelected = ( student.course == options[i] ) ? "selected" : "";
%>  
    <option value="<%=options[i]%>" <%=isSelected %>>
        <%= options[i] %>
    </option>
<%
}
%>
</select>
```